# Solving for a limit with an indeterminate fraction and square root of X

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a test tomorrow and there's one thing I found that I don't understand while reviewing. I've looked all over YouTube and Google and just can't find out how to work this problem:

$$ \lim_{x\to16} \frac{x-16}{4-\sqrt{x}} $$

It's obvious that it's indeterminate but I can't get any further than that.

Comment: You can always use L'Hôpital's Rule

Comment: This should probably have been a comment, but you cannot yet make them.

Comment: ...but if you can, avoid using it. :)

Comment: @Ronnie: I have converted your answer to a comment. As Mariano mentioned, because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, you didn't do anything wrong; the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points. Here is an [explanation of reputation points](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want to find
$$\lim_{x\to 16}\frac{x-16}{4-\sqrt{x}}.$$

Multiply "top" and "bottom" by $4+\sqrt{x}$. That is perfectly legitimate, we are multiplying our expression by $1$.  Since $(4-\sqrt{x})(4+\sqrt{x})=16-x$, 
$$\lim_{x\to 16}\frac{x-16}{4-\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\to 16}\frac{(x-16)(4+\sqrt{x})}{(4-\sqrt{x})(4+\sqrt{x})}=\lim_{x\to 16}\frac{(x-16)(4+\sqrt{x})}{16-x}.$$

When $x \ne 16$, our expression simplifies to $-(4+\sqrt{x})$. This is because $x-16=(-1)(16-x)$. So our limit is equal to
$$\lim_{x\to 16} -(4+\sqrt{x}).$$

It is clear that this last limit is $-8$. If we want to mention fine details, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 16}\sqrt{x}=4$ because $\sqrt{x}$ is *continuous* at $x=16$.

**Remark**: Here is an alternative way of doing the same thing.  Note that for non-negative $x$,
$x-16=(\sqrt{x}-4)(\sqrt{x}+4)$.

Thus we are interested in
$$\lim_{x\to 16}\frac{(\sqrt{x}+4)(\sqrt{x}-4)}{4-\sqrt{x}}.$$
The rest is straightforward.

Comment: I tried this, but ended up with the same exact problem I started with.

Comment: @Joe: What did you get after performing this multiplication? Did you cancel what can be cancelled? Alternatively: $x-16=(\sqrt x-4)(\sqrt x+4)$

Comment: I hadn't noticed you could cancel x-16 with 16-x. The answer my teacher gave us was -8, though. How is that?

Comment: Is it negative because it's 16-x and x-16? Would x-16 and x-16 make it positive? I'm sort of confused with the signs here.

Comment: @Joe: Yes, $x-16=(-1)(16-x)$, so when you divide $x-16$ by $16-x$, you get $-1$.  And yes, $(x-16)/(x-16)=1$, positive.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{{x - 16}}{{4 - \sqrt x }} = \frac{{(x - 16)(4 + \sqrt x )}}{{(4 - \sqrt x )(4 + \sqrt x )}} = \frac{{(x - 16)(4 + \sqrt x )}}{{16 - x}} =  - (4 + \sqrt x ) \to  - 8
$$
as $x \to 16$.